# Why does ajax not post when I don't have a comma before send?

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have a very simple ajax setup and it was working perfectly.

```
function ajax_post(){
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var f = "foo";
    var j = "bar";
    hr.open("POST", "ajax7.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var rd = hr.responseText;
        }
    }
    hr.send("f="+f+"&j="+j);
}
```

Then I decided to slim it down by removing all the whitespace so I ended up with

```
function ajax_post(){var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();var f = "foo";var j = "bar";hr.open("POST", "ajax7.php", true);hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");hr.onreadystatechange = function(){if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){ var rd = hr.responseText;}}hr.send("f="+f+"&j="+j)}
```

And it stopped working, throwing an error.
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

So, I finally fixed it by adding a comma before hr.send in the one line version and it is working again.

My question...What is the significance of that comma? It works in the "expanded" version without it. Should I actually have been putting that comma in the "expanded" version all along...?

Comment: `var foo = function(){}bar();`, `var foo = function(){},bar();`  and `var foo = function(){}; bar();` are three very different programs. While adding a comma may make the program syntactically correct, it won't work as you intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the significance of that comma?

The comma makes the program syntactically correct.

```
var foo = function(){}bar();
```

is simply invalid because you cannot have two expression (`function(){}` is a *function expression*, `bar()` is a *call expression*) adjacent to each other without an operator. The comma is such an [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

```
var foo = function(){},bar();
```

Because of the way the comma operator works, this has the same effect as directly assigning `bar()` to `foo`:

```
var foo = bar();
```

So, even if adding the comma makes your program syntactically correct, it won't produce the result you want. In your specific case this would assign the return value of `hr.send()` to `hr.onreadystatechange`, which really doesn't make any sense:

```
// hr.onreadystatechange = function(){}, hr.send();
// is equivalent to
hr.onreadystatechange = hr.send();
```

You really need to add a semicolon to get two separate statements:

```
var foo = function(){}; bar();
```

Many statements, such as the *variable declaration statement*, are terminated by semicolons. The addition of the semicolon after the function expression tells the parser that the variable declaration statement ends there, and that the following part (`bar();`) is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I think I get it now.